# Is the inequality in Hoeffding's lemma ever tight?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

The Hoeffding Lemma asserts that $X$ is a random variable bounded between $[a,b]$ then
$$\mathbf{E}[e^{\lambda (X - \mathbf{E}[X])}] \leq e^{\lambda^2(b-a)^2/8}$$

A typical example which asks us to show tightness of the above bound is using symmetric random variables. $X$ s.t. $X$ takes value $a$ w.p. $1/2$ and $b$ w.p. $1/2$.

WLOG Lets take $a$ and $b$ to be $-1$ and $1$. Thus a symmetric rademacher variable.
The LHS of the Hoeffding inequality gives us $\frac{e^\lambda + e^{-\lambda}}{2}$ and the RHS gives us $e^{\lambda^2/2}$.

I dont see any way how these expressions can be same. More generally except for constant random variables I dont see anyway this inequality could hold as an equality. Are there non trivial examples where the above inequality holds with equality

Answer (score 5):

Checking the proof on wikipedia of [Hoeffding lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma), it may well be the case that no distribution saturates simultaneously the two inequalities involved, as you say : saturating the first inequality implies to work with r.v. concentrated on $\{a,b\}$, and then $L(h)$ (as defined in the brief proof on wiki) is not a quadratic polynomial indeed.

However, the point of the inequality is to be used for very small $\lambda$'s (see [Hoeffding inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality)), and in this case, you can check that the expansions of the two expressions

$$(e^\lambda + e^{-\lambda})/2 
\text{ and  }
e^{\lambda^2/2}$$

near $0$ coincide up to second order, and the latter expression is just more convenient to work with.